# Can somebody explain the last method in this code?

Tags: java, bubble-sort

I'm a beginner programmer and I don't understand the last method (`mysort`) in this code. It's actually an example for bubble sort.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Sort
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] a = {22, 55, 44, 11, 33};
    disp(a);
    mysort(a);
    disp(a);
}
public static void disp(int[] x)
{
    for(int e : x)
    {
        System.out.print(e + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void mysort(int[] a)
{
    int l = a.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < l - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < l - 1 - i; j++)
        {
            if(a[j + 1] < a[j])
            {
                int temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: As you noted, this is an implementation of bubble sort. Are you asking how bubble sort works?

Comment: I know the mechanism of bubble sort but i can't relate it to this code.

Comment: Can you briefly explain what happens in the last method? it might seem very simple for you but as I told earlier i'm new to programming, so i can't some of the basic stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use Arrays.sort()?

Comment: @Distjubo Probably because they are learning algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down each piece of the method. The first part of the code to understand is the inner most block:

```
int temp = a[j];
a[j] = a[j + 1];
a[j + 1] = temp;
```

If we were to run the above statements on the array `{1,2,3,4,5}`, with `j=2`, We would have:

```
int temp = a[2] --> 3;
a[2] = a[2+1] --> a = {1,2,4,4,5};
a[2+1] = temp --> a = {1,2,4,3,5};
```

We now see that these three lines swap the elements of `a[j]` and `a[j+1]`.

Now we look at the for loops. The inner loop: `for(int j = 0; j < l - 1 - i; j++)` is looping from the start of the array up to `l-1-i`. At each index, it asks `if(a[j+1] < a[j])`, meaning "is the element at index `j+1` smaller than the element at index `j`", or more concretely, "Should the elements at `j+1` and `j` be swapped?"

The outer loop is simply running over the whole array with index variable `i`. Taking the two loops together, we see that `j` will first loop over the whole array without the last index, then the whole array without the last two indices, then without the last three, etc. For example, if `l = 10`, `j` will take on the values:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 //i = 0, l - 1 - i = 9
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7   //i = 1, l - 1 - i = 8
0 1 2 3 4 5 6     //i = 2, l - 1 - i = 7
...
0
```

So the two for loops together are running over some fraction of the array `l` times, making swaps.

The reason for the loops being formed this way is that after each iteration of `j=0...l-1-i`, the last element is known to be in its sorted location, so we don't have to check it again. That justification and more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: If you find some answer to be helpful, please consider voting up in stead of commenting. It's time saving, author is rewarded with reputation, and notification is avoided. Cheers....

Answer (score 2):

This is explanation for above code:

Let us take the array of numbers "5 1 4 2 8", and sort the array from lowest number to greatest number using bubble sort. In each step, elements written in bold are being compared. Three passes will be required.

First Pass:
( 5 1 4 2 8 ) to ( 1 5 4 2 8 ), Here, algorithm compares the first two elements, and swaps since 5 > 1.

( 1 5 4 2 8 ) to ( 1 4 5 2 8 ), Swap since 5 > 4

( 1 4 5 2 8 ) to ( 1 4 2 5 8 ), Swap since 5 > 2

( 1 4 2 5 8 ) to ( 1 4 2 5 8 ), Now, since these elements are already in order (8 > 5), algorithm does not swap them.

Second Pass:
( 1 4 2 5 8 ) to ( 1 4 2 5 8 )

( 1 4 2 5 8 ) to ( 1 2 4 5 8 ), Swap since 4 > 2

( 1 2 4 5 8 ) to ( 1 2 4 5 8 )

( 1 2 4 5 8 ) to ( 1 2 4 5 8 )

Now, the array is already sorted, but the algorithm does not know if it is completed. The algorithm needs one whole pass without any swap to know it is sorted.

Third Pass:
( 1 2 4 5 8 ) to ( 1 2 4 5 8 )

( 1 2 4 5 8 ) to ( 1 2 4 5 8 )

( 1 2 4 5 8 ) to ( 1 2 4 5 8 )

( 1 2 4 5 8 ) to ( 1 2 4 5 8 )

Check this link for more explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Answer (score 1):

`mysort` loops through the given array `for(int j = 0; j < l - 1 - i; j++)` once for each element in the array `for(int i = 0; i < l - 1; i++)`.

```
if(a[j + 1] < a[j])
    {
        int temp = a[j];
        a[j] = a[j + 1];
        a[j + 1] = temp;
    }
```

The above just swaps the two integers so the larger one comes second.

Start: 1753 
Pass 1: **17**53 (no swap) 
Pass 1: 1**57**3 (swap) 
Pass 1: 15**37** (no swap) 
Pass 2: **15**37 (no swap) 
Pass 2: 1**35**7 (swap) 
Pass 2: 13**57** (no swap) 
Pass 3: **13**57 (no swap) 
Pass 3: 1**35**7 (no swap) 
Pass 3: 13**57** (no swap) 
Finish: 1357